# I need the wmic command to find updates of 3rd party applications in windows machine

Tags: windows, .net-4.0

I need the wmic command to find updates of 3rd party applications in windows machine. 
****i have tried c:\windows\system 32> wmic product get /format but i didnt find any updates.****

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a general way to find updates on windows

if you run

```
wmic product get name, urlupdateinfo
```

you might get some links (not all programs include this field)but this gives general urls which might help a user
find updates not something you can check programatically.